# How to handling session data in separated Javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, thymeleaf

When i need the checking process with session data, then how to use session data in separated javascript source?

```
// Session name = "userinfo"

A.html
<script src="/src.../check.js">

check.js
let session = ??? // <- how to get session data
if (session.data === null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't sesson data handled at the server-side? Sensitive data should not be loaded to the client.

Comment: Thank you! if i need check something (not important data) then i should check through cookie.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a bit more information of what you want to do ..?

Comment: about session check login user or not.

Comment: Again, such information should be handled on the server-side. You can read about  [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)s, though I'd send the session cookie with `http-only` header ...

Comment: Is this question regarding sessionStorage? If so, first take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage